# Async dispatch call in typescript from presentation component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

here in this tutorial https://redux.js.org/advanced/exampleredditapi in the section containing `containers/AsyncApp.js` they have code that looks like

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
  dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
}
```

but I don't know what they are doing here. I am trying to follow their example except in a project with typescript. Currently i get this runtime error from the chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a functon
    at ProxyComponent.componentDidMount (MyComponent.tsx?23ad:27)
```

My component code looks like this

```
export interface MyProps {
    prop1: any[]
}

type MyComponentProps = MyProps & DispatchProp;

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyState> {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchAsyncData());
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export { MyComponent };
```

The dispatch function is meant to call an async action in my redux code. I tried including something called DispatchProps to obtain the dispatch function in my props, but it clearly hasn't worked. Where does this dispatch function come from?

Comment: *Where does this dispatch function come from?* - from `connect`. There's no `connect` in the code you've posted. It's unclear what happens with MyComponent next but you likely don't connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining your `dispatch` function? Are you doing it using connect? 
 Regardless, you need to define your DispatchProp interface like you did with MyProps

```
export interface MyProps {
   prop1: any[]
}

export interface DispatchProp {
   dispatch: () => void // unsure what the actual type of your dispatch function is 
}

type MyComponentProps = MyProps & DispatchProp;


...
```

If you're trying to use connect to define your props, it would look something like this

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<any>): DispatchProp {
    return {
      dispatch: () =>
        dispatch({ type: "some_action_type", payload: somePayload})
    };
}
```